# Is my Xperia Z3 hopelessly locked or there's still second chance? (Forgot pattern, USB debugging on but not OEM unlock so can't flash)

Tags: sony-xperia, locked-out, flashtool, sony-xperia-z3

So basically I have a Stock Sony Xperia Z3 Docomo variant (if I recall correctly it was D6653) that I used all the way from 2017, until I had to store it on my desk cabinet for two years because the screen was broken (although before the screen went completely messed up, I managed to enable USB debugging in order to mirror the screen on my laptop with scrcpy so I can use it). Until finally I got a chance to replace the screen earlier this weekend

Problem is, I already forgot the pattern to unlock it. Not even my brother (who used it sometimes to game back then) remember the pattern. Worse part is some of the SIM card, even when it does have data plan (I just simply put the SIM from my other phone), the phone is just going to show as full bar Roaming (R) and no internet at all so this phone completely have no network (although I do also have suspicion that data connection is probably disabled), and obviously that means I can't use google account to unlock it

Wanted to use TWRP or Aroma File Manager to delete the pattern lock file, but then I realized I have to flash recovery first, and even if I do now understand how to do it on Z3 model because I already read various guide from various forum since Saturday, the problem is that OEM unlock isn't even enabled simply because at the time it was still a bit functional, I don't see it as something I need, as I don't root or flash a custom ROM on any phone that I use. And as additional note, as time goes on obviously all of the laptop at home had gone many clean reinstall, which means no ADB key backup, and I can't authorize because pattern lock

Is there hope left, or this phone is completely locked?

(TLDR: Phone locked because I forgot lock pattern, no Internet, data stuck at R, no connection so I can't recover with google account, USB Debugging on but not OEM unlock)

Comment: not sure what is the question, assume you want to recover its data. first get linux (or Re LiveDVD) from rufus pendrive and do full dump from [edl.py](https://github.com/bkerler/edl) come back here when done

Comment: @alecxs I want to remove the pattern. About the data... At this point I don't really mind that much since I still have the backup before the entire screen got messed up.

Comment: I am not quite sure if FRP even kicks in.. and it looks like device isn't encrypted at all. so deleting locksettings.db is probably easy. But if you don't care about data, either do factory reset from [recovery](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/sony/sony-xperia-z3-d6653/recovery-mode) (only do that if bonded google account password is known FRP?) or factory reset from suggested raw flash tool (erase userdata + cache partitions)

Comment: the *"backup user data"* option in recovery is nice.. do you have it? my scripts removes locksettings.db in case you want to [restore](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3899918) backup from TWRP or [convert](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3775129)/unpack on PC (unencrypted backup only)